# Connection to tcp://smtp.mailtrap.io:587 Timed Out

Tags: php, laravel

I tried loading my page I created using laravel and after I hit the registration button and I got the above error message, please what must I do?

Comment: Did you configure mailtrap with your credentials?

Comment: no. how do I do that pls

Comment: I posted my answer just below.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code you are using and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Mailtrap is an email testing service for testing. It will catch all the mail sent from your application, so you can test mails without sending it to client. In order to use it, you have to follow these steps:

First you have to create an account on [Mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/). Then go to your dashboard and note your credentials. It may be something like:

```
Username: 05921688469af01
Password: 2efe39296ae5b7f
```

Then paste this values in your `.env` file of your Laravel application (the username must be pasted in `MAIL_USERNAME` and the password must be pasted in `MAIL_PASSWORD`).

It might look like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=05921688469af01
MAIL_PASSWORD=2efe39296ae5b7f
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Then try again and it will work! You can go to your Mailtrap dashboard to see the result.

Comment: I have been tearing my hair out wondering why this wasn't working. It turns out that you need to include the line `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null`, I had just not included it as I thought it would default to null, but it defaults to `SSL` which means that the emails are being sent but Laravel still throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another SMTP port (2525, 465 or 25) https://mailtrap.io/faq#faq14

And also make sure to set your credentials which you got from [mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/faq#faq14) in `.env`file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io 
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=your mailtrap username
MAIL_PASSWORD=your mailtrap password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: I did that but still got the error msg: Connection to smtp.mailtrap.io:587 Timed Out

Comment: Expected response code 220 but got code "503", with message "503 TLS not available ..this happened wen I reloaded d page

Comment: its Very Simple Use . MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Answer (score 0):

Check below settings if you are using in your .env file of root folder of project.

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.yourdomainname.com

MAIL_PORT=2525

MAIL_USERNAME=email@yourdomainname.com

MAIL_PASSWORD= ********

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

**Or**

if you are using Gmail for sending a email then do following settings.

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com

MAIL_PORT=465

MAIL_USERNAME=******@gmail.com

MAIL_PASSWORD=*****

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl