# Laravel 5.8 Email Verification Email Not send

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm creating laravel registration email verification but my link is not sent to the mail. I'm doing this from localhost please help me and suggest me the answer.

**user model**

```
<?PHP

namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;


class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
use Notifiable, HasApiTokens, HasRoles;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var arra
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'phone', 'purpose', 'country', 'state'
];



/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];

public function videorecordings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Videorecordings::class);
}
public function rearcameras()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Rearcameras::class);
}
public function calllog()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Calllog::class);
}
public function callrecordings()
{
    return $this->hashMany(Callrecordings::class);
}
public function messages()
{
    return $this->hashMany(Messages::class);
}
public function fbcallrecordings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Fbcallrecordings::class);
}

}
```

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=*********
MAIL_PASSWORD=*********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**rote**

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

**dashboard controller**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
}
```

[image: verification page after signup]

and I'm saving user data using ajax and it's working but link not sent to user email for verification.
please check my code and help me overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: cleared the cache? also, try with https://mailtrap.io/, and then use gmail, in order to first be sure that your system works, and then solve all the problem with authentications and so on that you will encounter  with gmail

Comment: @Berto99 sir thank you for your response but now I get this message Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.mailtrap.io:2525 (Connection timed out)...please tell me how to overcome this error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321328/connection-to-tcp-smtp-mailtrap-io587-timed-out